Table content is right aligned instead of left?
My text of the columns is right aligned. I tried the
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}`

and
\usepackage{array}

but nothing is working.
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\stretch{1}}}*{7}{r}@{}}
\toprule
& ROil & $\Delta$ RCD & $\Delta$ RCC   \\
\midrule
Mean....      & -0.057 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
Min & -32 & 0.00 & 0.13  \\
Max & 12 & 0.39 & 0.02   \\
Std. Dev & 4.013 & 0.08 & 0.00   \\
Skewness & -2.10 & 0.08 & 0.00    \\
Kurtosis & 17 & 0.08 & 0.00   \\
\bottomrule                             
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}



You have specified r columns so they right align. Also you should use tabular* not tabularx as you have no X columns

Welcome to TeX.SE.

@DavidCarlisle. Thank you so much...It worked

You're mixing and mismatching the machineries of the tabularx and tabular* environments. Either use the tabularx approach and start using the R column type (or, rather, the L column type), or switch from tabularx to tabular* (and switch from the r to the l column type).
A separate comment: As the table has just four columns, I can't see a valid reason for specifying it to have seven [7!] columns.
Speaking for myself, I'd say that employing a tabular* environment and left-aligning the contents of the first column and centering the contents of columns 2 thru 4 looks best.

\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\blurb{% % common material
\toprule
& ROil & $\Delta$RCD & $\Delta$RCC \\
\midrule
Mean      & $-0.057$ & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
Min       & $-32$    & 0.00 & 0.13  \\
Max       & 12       & 0.39 & 0.02  \\
Std.\ Dev & 4.013    & 0.08 & 0.00  \\
Skewness  & $-2.10$  & 0.08 & 0.00  \\
Kurtosis  & 17       & 0.08 & 0.00  \\
\bottomrule}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\columnwidth}{@{} LLLL @{}}
\blurb                            
\end{tabularx}

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} llll @{}}
\blurb                            
\end{tabular*}

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l ccc @{}}
\blurb                           
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}


Addendum to address the OP's follow-up comment/request.

But now there is no way I am being able to add table notes under it. I tried "threeparttable", "multicolumn", "minipage", the minute I do anything, either the columns move about or its showing error.

Next time, please be more specific -- both about what you're actually doing and about the nature of the unsatisfactory result (or error message) you're getting. Anyway, encasing the tabular* environment and its associated notes in a minipage environment, of width \columnwidth, shouldn't cause any problems.

\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l ccc @{}}
\toprule
& ROil & $\Delta$RCD & $\Delta$RCC \\
\midrule
Mean      & $-0.057$ & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
Min       & $-32$    & 0.00 & 0.13  \\
\bottomrule                           
\end{tabular*}

\medskip\footnotesize
Notes: \lipsum[1][1-4] % filler text
\end{minipage}

\end{document}


Mico, Thank you so much(I tried to tag you but it doesn't work). I did your suggestion for tabular*. The table looks perfect. But now there is no way I am being able to add table notes under it. I tried "threeparttable", "multicolumn", "minipage", the minute I do anything, either the columns move about or its showing error....Can you suggest how to add tablenotes with your last option of tabular*

@nadeem - Please see the addendum I posted.

@mico- Thank you for the addendum and apologies for not posting the comment correctly. One last follow up question, what part of the code ensures that the three or four or 5  columns after the first column are equally spaced such that the table fits the document text width? Becuase I am now using same code with another table \begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l cccc @{} but the remaining 4 columns are not equally spaced and the last column does not reach till the end of the table the way we have RCC in the above example.

@nadeem - If I understand your comment correctly, you're now dealing with a different table -- one that has 5 columns, not 4. As I have no idea of how your new table may differ from the earlier one, I am in no position to judge what may be going on. Please post a new query to ask about how to go about formatting the new table.

I believe you're using a two-column format, otherwise it would non make sense to expand a four column table to the text width.
For tables displaying numeric data, siunitx offers many very useful features. In this case, since the data in the second column aren't homogeneous, I'd go with center alignment (but in math mode).
In order to add table notes you need nothing special.
\documentclass[12pt,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{table}[htp]

\begin{tabular*}{\columnwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  >{$}c<{$}
  S[table-format=1.2]
  S[table-format=1.2]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{ROil} & {$\Delta$RCD} & {$\Delta$RCC} \\
\midrule
Mean      & -0.057 & 0.00 & 0.00  \\
Min       & -32    & 0.00 & 0.13  \\
Max       & 12     & 0.39 & 0.02  \\
Std.\ Dev & 4.013  & 0.08 & 0.00  \\
Skewness  & -2.10  & 0.08 & 0.00  \\
Kurtosis  & 17     & 0.08 & 0.00  \\
\bottomrule                             
\end{tabular*}

\smallskip

\small
Notes. \lipsum[2][1-3]

\caption{A table caption}
\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}


